# TWI Wire.setClock() on non arduino AVR MCU issue

Tags: i2c, avr, avrdude, wire-library

Using an Atmega168P - programmed by means of `avrdude` with the `.hex` file generated by Arduino IDE.

The following code sets the 8 MHz Atmega's TWI interface to just 15.625 kHz:

```
  Wire.begin(); // Initiate the Wire library
  Wire.setClock(100* 1000);
  delay(10);
```

While this one doubles it to 31.25 kHz:

```
  Wire.begin(); // Initiate the Wire library
  TWBR = (F_CPU/(100*1000) - 16)/2;
  TWSR &= 0b11111100;
  delay(10);
```

Looking to get 100 kHz clock. What am I missing ?

Comment: Calculations are int (16-bits) by default. Try 100*1000L. Or better define F_TWI as 100000L and use TWBR = ((F_CPU/F_TWI)-16)/2;

Comment: @MikaelPatel That was it! You may want to turn that into an answer as well, thanks.

Comment: You get 100kHz with just Wire.begin(), because that is the default. The Wire.setClock has limits (I don't know the limits) but 50kHz to 200kHz should work: Wire.setClock(50000L) to Wire.setClock(200000L). I hope you are not trying to compile 16MHz code for a 8MHz ATmega chip. If there is no 8MHz ATmega168P in the menu, you should create an entry in boards.txt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Looking to get 100 kHz clock. What am I missing?

Calculations are int (16-bits) by default in AVR GCC. Try 100*1000L. Or even better:

```
#define F_TWI 100000L
```

and use:

```
TWBR = ((F_CPU/F_TWI)-16)/2;
```

or:

```
Wire.setClock(F_TWI);
```

Cheers!